# How to use Finder labels in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, mac, windows-explorer, finder, label

From what I've found there is no app that allows Windows users to see and edit Mac color labels, however I'm looking into what it would take to make one. From what I've read, it sounds like the app would need to access the .DS_store files which are difficult to read. Whenever I try opening .DS_store files, a lot of the characters don't display correctly, and changing the color values doesn't seem to update the labels. I'm guessing this is a proprietary Apple format.

If anyone has had any success opening and manipulating the tag section of .DS_store files, I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

[note: apologies for the original off-topic title, I'm relatively new to SuperUser]

Comment: This is going to get closed as a 'software rec' but I wish we could find an answer to this one, personally. afaik, it is simply not possible.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: You could try rewriting the question to be more 'What data is needed to be able to read the label info', rather than 'what app can...' as there isn't an app yet but I'd buy one if there was ;)